# How to change the size of the font in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to adjust the font-size for Visual Studio 2013, specifically the TFS window.   It seems none of the options inside Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors does anything to affect this.   Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible. Fonts setting is related to the font of code not windows of the Visual Studio. These fonts are set according to theme of th VS. Or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow for the longest time I did not think this was possible but just found a way to do it.  This works for all windows like TFS and solution explorer.

1. Go to Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors
2. In "Show Settings for" chose "Environment Font"
3. In "Font" replace Automatic to for example, Arial and change size.

Comment: In VS2010, already had the Environment Font set but it was not begin respected by TFS pending changes.   Setting it again had the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

use

`ctrl+ scrollup` (using mouse) to increase size

`ctrl+ scrolldown` for decreasing font size.

Comment: It is not what @Chris asked.